# Is it possible to move RAID5 arrays in and out of a synology NAS

Tags: nas, synology, raid-5

Basically we want to move our current 5x12tb drives (In raid5) out of the unit and store them in the cupboard.
Then we want to  put in new 16tb drives also in raid5.

Is it possible for us to put back the original 12tb drives if we need to access the data?

Can the synology just read it automatically? Is there a rebuild or something required?

Help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: With RAID5 in general this should be possible *if the controller is the same* (brand/family/type), I'll leave it to someone familiar with Synology's implementation to answer this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as:

- The drives are removed all at once, when the device is powered off
- They are put back in all at once, when the device is powered off
- And all drives survive

It should be possible. Try to put them back in the same bays (order) too. Synology devices should deal with shuffled disks fine, but it would be safer to not make it have to.

You may experience a little hiccup if you'll update the DSM in the meantime, with the other disk set. Synology doesn't allow OS downgrades, so if it detects that the "old" set of drives is running an older version that was previously installed on the "new" set, it will force you to update the "old" set before you'll be able to use it.

It may be worth noting that Synology uses a standard, non-proprietary on-disk format, and the disks should be readable on any computer running Linux (although you have to connect all of them).

**Additional Resource:** [HDD migration limitations](https://Synology%20https://kb.synology.com/en-global/DSM/tutorial/How_to_migrate_between_Synology_NAS_DSM_6_0_and_later#x_anchor_id7:%7E:text=by%20Configuration%20Backup-,HDD%20migration%20limitations,-Model%20limitations)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great detailed explanation